# typedef function pointer that takes argument ClassName* before defining ClassName?

Tags: c++, syntax, g++, function-pointers, typedef

I have the following situation:

```
typedef void (*F_POINTER)(ClassName*);

class ClassName {
    public:
        F_POINTER f;
}
```

This happens because an instance of ClassName needs to pass a pointer itself to the client. However, If I write things in this order, I get complains about ClassName not declared, whatnot. However, if I switch them around, I get complains about F_POINTER not being declared when I declare the instance in the class.

So maybe I'm missing something simple here, but how would I accomplish this?

Comment: What is the return type for `F_POINTER`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forward declaration:

```
class ClassName;

typedef (*F_POINTER)(ClassName*);

class ClassName {
    public:
        F_POINTER f;
}
```

Or shorter:

```
typedef (*F_POINTER)(class ClassName*); // implicit declaration;
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working under GCC 4.5.2 (mingw32):

```
typedef void (*F_POINTER)(class ClassName);
class ClassName {};
void f (ClassName) {}

int main ()
{
    F_POINTER x = f;
}
```

I wouldn't trust my life on whether it is legal C++ or not, not even the pointer version described by other people. Forward declarations and pointers do not solve everything, for example it is not possible to declare methods that throw pointers of incomplete types, you need full definition for that. This might be similarly illegal, just accepted by compilers.

Comment: It's perfectly legal to *declare* function parameters of an incomplete class type, even in the non-pointer case: your definition of `F_POINTER` above is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Forward declare `ClassName`. The type can be incomplete to use a pointer to it.

```
class ClassName;
typedef (*F_POINTER)(ClassName*);

class ClassName { ... };
```

Alternatively, move the `typedef` inside the class. Also consider using `boost::function`/`std::function` instead of function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can forward declare it as,

```
class ClassName;
typedef void (*F_POINTER)(ClassName*); // assume that return is `void`
```

before the `F_POINTER` or you can use the `template` trick to avoid such hassels for every `class`:

```
template<typename RETURN, typename ARGUMENT>
struct FuncPtr {  typedef RETURN (*F_POINTER)(ARGUMENT); };
```

[Usage](http://www.ideone.com/uEDOI):

```
class ClassName {
public:
  FuncPtr<void,ClassName*>::F_POINTER f;
};
```